# kext for 10.4 - 10.6

Tags: macos

I have a filter scheme driver with four binaries for 10.4 PPC, 10.4 i386, 10.5 & 10.6 i386 and 10.6 x86_64.  I need to put them all into one kext.  I don't think I can just lipo them together because of the two different i386 binaries.

How can I get them all into the same kext bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Apple's [SimpleUserClient](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleUserClient/index.html) example: you can use sub-kexts for each OS revision.

Note that you may need to tweak the build settings a bit because later `ld` versions insert a load command that the earlier kernel linker doesn't understand; see [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-kernel/2009/Feb/msg00042.html) mailing list message (and the surrounding thread, if you need more context).

(Why on earth was this question marked "non programming related"?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have four separate binaries, you cannot put them into the same kext bundle.  You can put up to two binaries into a bundle by putting one bundle into the Plugins directory of the other bundle; the Plugin will match if the inital driver does not.  However, if there are no API changes between your kexts, you may be able to use a kext compiled for 10.4 on 10.5 and 10.6, or one compiled for 10.5 on 10.6.